# Customizing Popup Box

Tags: javascript, popup

Greetings fellow earthlings,

I am trying to customize a popup box.  I don't want it to have the browser junk.  I want to start with just a plain 400px by 400px gray square in which I can put use my own graphics to create the 'X' (close) button.  I have tried looking for a site to assist me, but have had no luck.  Is this too complicated or am I overlooking something.  If anyone knows how to do this please help me.

Live Long and Prosper.

Comment: I have tried what I just described above Mike...

Comment: What I meant is, where is your code? Can you post where you're at so we can see what you've done?

Comment: var name=prompt("Please enter your name","");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a modal window.  [Here](http://www.webgurusdesignblog.com/2009/02/10-best-modal-boxes-for-web-design-projects/) is a list of pre-built programs or you can build your own.   Check here for [how to](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFgQFjAA&url=http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial&ei=QO31T_ZC6c7aBfHTmN4G&usg=AFQjCNHAR18UrfryyCOWQMvwoMUvVK8cpQ&sig2=0FX3dqNzFvMWwnbskZV99w) with jQuery.

Comment: Thank you sir.  Can you customize these modal windows and add info in them too?

Comment: Yes, there are a variety of ways to do this.  I would recommend using a pre-built tool.  No need to rebuild the wheel.